# Standard deviation in Google Sheets Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have data of jobs (A), their executions (B) and duration (C) in my Google Sheet. I have already calculated the average duration of each job with Query language:

```
SELECT A, B, AVG(C) GROUP BY A, B
```

How do I calculate standard deviation?

I found the [discussion](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/dBPrGwZVzKk) suggesting usage of `ARRAYFORMULA` and calculating standard deviation from original math equations but I'm looking for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

It always helps to be able to see the actual sheet and data. However, you can run STDEV on a QUERY or on the data it produces.

So let's say you have your QUERY in E2: `=QUERY(A:C, "Select A, B, AVG(C) GROUP BY A, B)`

That would put your numbers in Column G. So, say in H2, you could use `=STDEV(G2:G)`.

Alternatively — if you didn't need to see the original QUERY output, just the STDEV of it — you could run the STDEV on a QUERY of the QUERY itself: `=STDEV(QUERY(QUERY(A:C, "Select A, B, AVG(C) GROUP BY A, B), "SELECT Col3"))`

Based on your data, you may need STDEVP instead of STDEV.